# Finding xpath from text with br

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this html code

```
<div>
  <span>test</span>
  foo
  <br />
  bar
</div>
```

And I'm trying to find it with the text directly inside the div (so foo bar).

Normally, I would go //div[normalize-space(text()) = 'foobar'], but because of the 
 it is not working. I tried to add spaces or special chars, or trim them, but nothing seem to work.

From tests I saw that

```
//div/text() = foo bar
//div/text()[1] = foo
//div/text()[2] = bar
//div[text()[1] = foo] = the div
//div[text()[2] = bar] = nothing
```

It seem that text() return only a index[2] when returning a value and not for searching a value.

I tested this code with java / selenium and firepath (a plugin of firebug to test xpath).

Anybody have an idea on how to get the div from the text, and if possible, without using contains because they are not accurate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use below `XPath` expression [to match required `div` by its text](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%3Cspan%3Etest%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20foo%0A%20%3Cbr%2F%3E%0A%20bar%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv[normalize-space()%3D%22test%20foo%20bar%22]%0A&=&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2):

```
//div[normalize-space()="test foo bar"]
```

Note that function to remove white-spaces called actually [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space), but not `sanitize-space()`

**Update**

If you want to use only `"foo"` and `"bar"` text nodes, then try

```
//div[concat(normalize-space(text()[2]), normalize-space(text()[3]))="foobar"]')
```

or if to use them separately

```
//div[normalize-space(text()[2])='foo' and normalize-space(text()[3])='bar']
```

Comment: Sadly, I do not always know the content of "test", so I have to rely only on foo bar

Comment: I've updated my question to incluse normalize-space, but your update work perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have an li with text 
"abx" \n
"-" \n
"xyz"\n


How do i identify this text?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try following:

```
  //span[text()='test']/ancestor::div
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
  //div[contains(.,'foo')]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
   //span/ancestor::div[contains(.,'foo')]
```

Comment: I'm trying to access with foo bar, it's the only data that I am certain of.

Comment: With this code, you lose precision. If I had a other div with the text fooooobar or foobaz it will return true.

Comment: Still, if the text inside the div is <div><span>test</span>foooooo<br />bar</div> it will return true when it should not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a doubt. Why `//div[contains(.,'foo')]` is working but not `//div[contains(text(),'foo')]`?