# How can I get the text from <a> in java using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I have

```
<a>
some
<br/>
text
</a>
```

I need xpath to get `"text"`. I have used

```
String getLinkText="//a[1]";    
browser.getCurrentWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(getLinkText)).getText();
```

It is giving `"some"` as a output but I need `"text"`. How can I get that?

Comment: check this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896877/finding-xpath-from-text-with-br/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `//a[contains(text(),'text')]` just because in the `<a>` tag you have some spaces.

Comment: I tried this xpath but it didn't show any matching nodes.

Comment: if you have firepath installed or just `ctrl+f` in Chrome you can see that the xpath is right and works (directly here on stackoverflow). The only thing different is that SO uses `span` for the code (`//span[contains(text(),'text')]`). But sure if your code is different as you posted the xpath is different too. In that case post the whole code to get a right xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do your task:

```
//First, get the full link text (your locator may vary)
String linkText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
//Split the text by spaces    
String [] splittedLink = linkText.split("\\s+");
//Get the last part of your text
String lastPartOfLink = splittedLink[splittedLink.length - 1];\
```

In your specific case you could use the one linear too:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText().split("\\s+")[1]
```